# How can you refine a json output extracted from a website?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a python script to extract this json output : https://api.deezer.com/playlist/1050179021/tracks

My problem is once I have extracted ['data'] with these lines, I want to select only the 'name' element in 'artist' :

```
url = f'https://api.deezer.com/playlist/1050179021/tracks'
user_response = requests.get(url)
n = user_response.json()['data']
```

What ways are there to do it if there are any ?
Happy to answer any questions to clarify any doubts.

Comment: once deserialized (which is what `user_response.json()` do), what you have are plain Python datatypes like dicts and lists. Those types are fully documented, starting with [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). IOW, it's just a matter of getting vaues from dicts and iterating over lists. So what is your problem exactly ??? (IOW: what have you tried that didn't work ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use list comprehension:

```
[e['artist']['name'] for e in n]
```

output:

```
['Testament',
 'Parkway Drive',
 'Avenged Sevenfold',
 'Heaven Shall Burn',
 'Bury Tomorrow',
 'Hollywood Undead',
 'allusinlove',
 'Sepultura',
 'Suicide Silence',
 'Lordi',
 'Vader',
 'Five Finger Death Punch',
 'Code Orange',
 'Russian Circles',
 'Breaking Benjamin',
 'In This Moment',
 'Apocalyptica',
 'Ozzy Osbourne',
 'Higher Power',
 'Body Count',
 'Intronaut',
 'Kvelertak',
 'Demons & Wizards',
 'Annihilator',
 'Antagonist A.D.']
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if when an artist is specified, there will always be a name available, if not:

```
[element['artist']['name'] for element in n if 'artist' in element and 'name' in element['artist']]
```

otherwise you can use:

```
[element['artist']['name'] for element in n if 'artist' in element]
```

This filters the list, so the final list will only contain artists. If you want the same list, but a None value when no artist is specified:

```
[element['artist']['name'] if 'artist' in element and 'name' in element['artist'] else None for element in n ]
```